# I have a 48" 1080p TV set and need to know the maximum resolution I can send from my computer

Tags: resolution, hdmi

My 48" screen is 1080p supporting 1920 x 1080 resolution.

I need to design a *canvas* on my computer that will send to this screen via HDMI cable.

Should the dimensions of this canvas be

- 1920 x 1080 pixels *or*
- 2862 x 1587 pixels (because 48" converted to pixels equals this in Illustrator)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set your Illustrator canvas to be at 1920x1080 pixels if you are going to be outputting ONLY on your 48" LCD as final.

I believe you got your Illustrator canvas size of 2862 x 1587 by using the diagonal 48" multiplied by a 72 ppi resolution - doesn't work that way bub.

However, in the event that you might be using your artwork for print or anything else, I would recommend you to set it to a higher resolution that supports fine-printing, and also is in a 16:9 aspect ratio, and then output to a jpeg and downscale to 1920x1080 for display on your LCD. That would cover all bases.

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1080p) would indicate that it's 1920x1080 (given the 16:9 aspect ratio).  Not sure where 2862x1587 comes from.

Answer (score 1):

**1920 x 1080** **is** 1080p 16:9 aspect (widescreen)

To calculate use 1080 as the base number.

```
1080 * (16/9) = 1920
```

and... Since 720 is also a 16:9 aspect

```
720 * (16/9) = 1280
```

So 720p is actually 720 x 1280 pixels resolution

Forget what illustrator says. Pixels are an arbitrary measurement indicating the number of red/green/blue dots on the screen. The pixel count in illustrator is measured by multiplying the resolution times the ppi (pixels per inch).